# bootstrap dropdown not working in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, dropdown

I wanted to show a dropdown on click of the img icon but the dropdown is not opening on click, Here is my code.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="user-image" style="background-image: url('../images/rafi.jpg');"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li>
        <div class="profile-pic">
            <img src="images/rafi.jpg" alt="Rafi Ali Khan">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>{{$scope.userLocalData[0].uname}}</h3></li>
    <li><a href="" class="text-right">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="text-right">Log Out</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure about your question. very unclear. But if it helps, https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @giri my question is that I'm using this code for showing a dropdown on click of the img tag, but on click nothing happens. Something like this... http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: i dont see any events binded to your image tag , you need to add a `ng-click` directive

Comment: @srv try adding that library and setting up since you are ussing angular, binding needs to be thru a directive. It might still work without, but I would recommend using the library i suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains some invalid HTML markup. For example, I assume you mean `role="button"` instead of `type="button"` for the anchor element. Also, you should use `href="#"` or `data-target="#"` instead of `href="javascript:void(0);"`. You could try this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="user-image" style="background-image: url('../images/rafi.jpg');"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li>
      <div class="profile-pic">
        <img src="images/rafi.jpg" alt="Rafi Ali Khan">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><h3>{{$scope.userLocalData[0].uname}}</h3></li>
    <li><a href="" class="text-right">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="text-right">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```